# Integrate Struts and Hibernate: AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource is only available on Java 1.5 and higher

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2

I am trying to integrate Hibernate and Struts 2

**This is `applicationContext.xml`:**

```xml
   <bean id="user" class="com.caveofprogramming.service.imp.UserImp" /> 
   <bean id="userSpringAction" class="com.caveofprogramming.actions.UserSpringAction"> 
    <property name="user" ref="user" /> </bean>
    
    <bean id="customerDAO" class="com.caveofprogramming.entity.CustomerDAO">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" /> </bean>
    
    <bean id="customerEntity" class="com.caveofprogramming.entity.Customer" />
     
     <bean id="customerAction" class="com.caveofprogramming.actions.CustomerAction"> 
    <property name="customerEntity" ref="customerEntity" /> 
    <property name="customerDAO" ref="customerDAO" /> 
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
            p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />
    
        <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
            p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
            p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
            p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
    
        <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="configLocation">
                <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
            </property>
            <property name="configurationClass">
                <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <tx:annotation-driven />
        <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean> 
        
    </beans>
```

I already have my `jdbc.properties` and saving my `Customer` in DAO:

**`CustomerDAO`:**

```
public class CustomerDAO {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void persistAuthor(Customer customer) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(customer);
    }
}
```

**This is `Entity` class:**

```
@Table(name="customer")
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
//Getter/Setters//
}
```

**This is my `Action` Class:**

```
public class CustomerAction extends ActionSupport {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomerAction.class);
    Customer customer;
    CustomerDAO customerdao;
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String password;

//GETTERS/SETTERS//

    @Action(value="/customer", results={
            @Result(name="success",location="/customerSuccess.jsp"),
        })
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        logger.debug("Hello");
    customer.setId(getId());
    customer.setName(getName());
    customer.setPassword(getPassword());
    customerdao.persistAuthor(customer);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

However, it shows me this exception

**Exception:**

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource is only available on Java 1.5 and higher
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:420)
```

Comment: Which java version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The Spring framework doesn't support your Java version, due to [`TxNamespaceUtils`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/springframework/transaction/config/TxNamespaceUtils.java.html) it could be a bug also reported as [Bug 1090968](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=1090968). You are not recommended to use old libraries with the latest Java 8. Try to upgrade some libraries, especially for Spring and Hibernate and change configuration to not use deprecated APIs.